# Check specific line of HTML in Java

Tags: java, ruby

I have the following ruby code which checks [www.usnwc.org](http://usnwc.org/) to see if their biking/running trails are open. Specifically, this checks an image which changes with the status of the trails:

```
require 'open-uri'
content = open('http://usnwc.org/#trail-status').read

if content =~ /trailsclosed\.png/
  puts "Trails closed!"
elsif content =~ /trailsopen\.png/
  puts "Trails open!"
else
  puts "Oops, images not found?" 
end
```

I would like to perform the same task in Java. So far I have the following code which gets the page and prints the whole html file to the console.

```
public class OpenURL {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL usnwc = new URL("http://www.usnwc.org/#trail-status");
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                usnwc.openStream()))) {
            String inputLine;
            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I check which image is present using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if (inputLine.contains("trailsclosed.png")) {
    // trails closed
}
```

Similar check can be made for trailsopen.png.

Once a match is found you can break the while loop.